# If statement with a variable without a loop

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and coding in general. I'm trying to declare a variable x to replace columns in a cell in excel. Something like that:

```
If Cells(2,1).Select Then
'do something
ElseIf Cells(2,2).Select Then
'do something else
...and so on up to Cells(2,10)
End If
```

I got the Private Sub to trigger the code when I select the cell, that's all good.
I would like to replace the columns from 1 to 10 with x but not using the For/Next because it is not a loop. If the condition is met stops right there.

I can't write

```
Dim x as Long
x = 1 to 10
```

It doesn't work either with x = "1" or "2" or "3" ....till 10

Should be an array I guess

```
Dim x as Variant
x = [1,2,3,...10]
'for x to take the values 1,2,3,....in if statement
```

how do I do it? ty

I will make it much clearer what I'm trying to accomplish here. In an Excel sheet I have 105 to 114 values in range("a1:j1"). When I press any of the cells in this range I need the value in cell M1 to take the value in the cell selected. If I press Cells(1,4).Value = 108 then Cells(1,13).Value becomes 108. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated description:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:J1")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("M1").Value = Target.Cells(1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```